# Volume of the intersection of two $n$-dimensional cubes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, packing-problem

Let $U \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a unitary matrix and $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $n$-dimensional cube centered at zero.   Let
\begin{align}
K_1=U \cdot K= \{ y: y=U x, x\in K\}.
\end{align}

That is $K_1$ is a rotation of $K$.  Next, let ${\rm Vol}(\cdot)$ be a volume operator (Lebesgue measure).

Can we give lower bounds on 
\begin{align}
{\rm Vol}( K_1 \cap K),
\end{align}

The upper bounds are simple
\begin{align}
{\rm Vol}( K_1 \cap K) \le \min ({\rm Vol}( K_1 ),{\rm Vol}( K)),
\end{align}
and tight if $U$ is an identiy matrix.

**Lower Bound Based on inclusion**
Let $B$ be a ball of radius $r$ such that
\begin{align}
B \subset K_1\cap K,
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)} r^n =Vol(B) \le  {\rm Vol}( K_1 \cap K)= 2^nr^n .
\end{align}

But,   since  $\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)} \to 0$ as  $n \to \infty$  and $2^n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, the lower and the upper bounds do not match.

**Question:** Can we come up with a lower bound and upper bounds of the same order as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$-norm ball of radius $\frac{1}{2},$ $K=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:\max_{i}|x_{i}|\leq 1/2\}.$  This is a unit cube centered at $0$, and it clearly contains the Euclidean unit ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}.$ If we apply a unitary transformation to $K,$ we get another unit cube centered at $0,$ but the Euclidean unit ball of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ remains unchanged, and is still clearly contained within $UK.$ Thus, given a collection of unitary matrices $\{U_{k}\}_{k\geq 1},$ we actually have that $$V_{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\leq \mathrm{Vol}\left(\bigcap_{k\geq1} U_{k}K\right),$$ if $K$ is an $n$-dimensional unit cube centered at $0,$ and where $V_{n}(r)$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean ball of radius $r$.

Comment: Thanks. Very, nice. Is this order tight?

Comment: In the case that there are only two cubes, I'm sure that it's not, but if we allow a countable intersection, I think that it probably is.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if have any ideas how to do this for the case of two intersections.

Comment: In the case $n=2,$ considering a rotation by an angle $\theta\in[0,\pi/4]$ (the other cases all follow by symmetry), and doing some geometry, we can see that the minimum area is achieved when $\theta=\pi/4,$ and the area is given by $2(\sqrt{2}-1)\approx 0.8284,$ which is better than the bound given here, which is about $0.7854.$